# Can we use static functions in multithreading environment?

Tags: multithreading, selenium, thread-safety, selenium-webdriver, static-methods

I'm new to Java and Selenium. In selenium test I want to check whether element is displayed  before performing any action on it. I have written static function to check for element existence. I'll be running tests in parallel, this function will be accessed in parallel by many tests. so I'm worried about threadsafety of static function . here is my code,

```
public static boolean untilElementAppears(Element obj, long maxTimeout){
    try{
        while(!obj.isDisplayed()){
            sleep(1);
            maxTimeout--;
            if(maxTimeout <= 0){
                return false;
            }
        }
    }catch(NoSuchElementException | StaleElementReferenceException e){
        untilElementAppears(obj, maxTimeout);
    }
    return true;
}
```

Here I'm worried about obj and maxTimeout parameters. Will these parameters mixed up while running parallel tests? I'm not using any static variables here.

Comment: The issue with multithreading isn't using *static methods*; the issue is *changing shared state* - doesn't matter if it's a static method or not. So, is *the object named by* `obj` shared? Does it matter if it is? And does Selenium claim/support threading itself?

Comment: @user2246674 Yes, Selenium supports threading. I need to check for existence of obj. I'll pass element (button / textfield / label... etc) to the method as obj in the test but this method will be called by many tests at the same time. for example, test01 will be checking for button existence while test02 will be checking for textfield  existence at the same time. will the obj of test01 and test02 will get mixed up in the method?

Comment: Here is ur answer - http://www.coderanch.com/t/535556/threads/java/static-variable-method-threadsafe